# "su <otheruser>" fails with "standard in must be atty"

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder, su

I researched this question and all answers suggest visudo to add:
Defaults:user !requiretty

It does not work!

I have two Linux boxes (RedHat). I have a Java class which uses ProcessBuilder/Process to execute commands.  The class runs under a system account.
On both boxes, I run

```
su other-user -c 'some-command'
```

and provide the password for other-user in an input stream to the Process object.

On one box, the command succeeds and on the other I get the error above.
The sudoers files on both machines did not have exclusions for requiretty ('Defaults requiretty' is set on both files).
I tried adding the exclusion as suggested by the answers I found. I tried both the system user running the process and 'other-user'...

Does not work.

What else can be the issue? Do I need to restart the system after adding the requiretty exceptoin(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudoers` is for `sudo` rather than `su` so you should use `sudo`.

According to `su` manual:

> `-c, --command COMMAND`
>
> Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its `-c`.
>
> The executed command will **have no controlling terminal**. This option cannot be used to execute interactive programs which need a controlling TTY.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a TTY spawning if you are trying to avoid using sudo or you don't have a sudo privileges.

Just invoke one of the following codes before running the code which giving you the error you mentioned.

here are some examples of codes you can use, depends on the code or the system you are using:

```
python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/bin/sh")' 

echo os.system('/bin/bash')

/bin/sh -i

perl —e 'exec "/bin/sh";'

perl: exec "/bin/sh";

ruby: exec "/bin/sh"

lua: os.execute('/bin/sh')
```

(From within IRB)

```
exec "/bin/sh"
```

(From within vi)

```
:!bash
```

(From within vi)

```
:set shell=/bin/bash:shell
```

(From within nmap)

```
!sh
```

the first three choices up are my common used ones, and I am trusting their results.
I am using them while pentesting.